# Dolby Vision with ffmpeg 5.0 to HLS stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

Is there a way to preserve Dolby Vision from an mkv to an hls stream with ffmpeg v5.0.1? So far I've tired `ffmpeg -i 'video.mkv' -c:v copy -f hls 'out.m3u8'` as well as using `libx265` with various commands using `-strict` and color parameters but to no avail. I've heard that ffmpeg version 5 and up have support for dolby vision but documentation on that is sparse to none.

Comment: Does [this link](https://codecalamity.com/encoding-uhd-4k-hdr10-videos-with-ffmpeg/#saving-dolby-vision) help?

Comment: It does somewhat. I have an rpu file but I'm seeing `Skipping NAL unit 63` from ffmpeg command while trying to pass in the rpu file. There is no dv in the output either. It's just HDR10.

Comment: I've been successful in passing through profile 7 from a source that has native Dolby Vision P7, but I can't get it to change profiles, even with a properly converted RPU file and all necessary parameters (`dolby-vision-profile`, `dolby-vision-rpu`, `repeat-headers`, `vbv-bufsize`, `vbv-maxrate`, etc.). I've given up for now and went back to piping with x265.